# plsql get particular sub string from givin string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a input string like following

```
'"sadf asd " <abc@google.com>'
'"asdf@google.com " <xyz@google.com>'
```

now i want to extract email address as following:

```
abc@google.com
xyz@google.com
```

how can i get it ?

Comment: Is the email address always between < >?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the address is always quoted by `<...>` and that there are no '`<`' or '`>`' in the first part of the string, you can use:

```
select regexp_replace('"asdf@google.com " <xyz@google.com>', '(.*)<(.*)>', '\2')
from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
select replace(replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR('"sadf@asd.com " <abc@google.com>','[<](\w+@(\w*.\w*)+)[>]'),'<',''),'>','')
from dual
```

This will return abc@google.com